# How can you determine if swf is played standalone or loaded in other swf?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loader

I have two swf's. One "show" of some sort, and one "menu" that acts as a loader for "shows". The "show" swf can run in its own respect, or by being loaded via the "menu".

Is there a way to determine, if the "show" is run stand-alone or as loaded into the "menu"?

One solution is to have the "menu's" `Loader` object set a variable on the loaded "show", like `myLoader.content.thisIsFromMenu = true;` and then checking in the "show", if such a variable exists and is true. BUT I was wondering, if there is any more generic way, that would not require for the "show" to know anything about the "menu" to determine, if it is loaded into a swf or played by itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (root.parent && root.parent == stage) {
  // Standalone
}
```

Comment: Correct indeed. Checking for `parent` instead of `root.parent` must have worked circumstantially, but might not always be correct. Thus  your answer is correct.

Answer (score 2):

In the constructor of loaded swf:

`if (stage && parent == stage) {/*I'm standalone*/}`

Or maybe `if (parent is Loader)` will also work (vice versa logic)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will try the second approach in the project.

Comment: you have to check root.parent, not just parent.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (root.name == "root1") //standalone
```

Comment: How would this be used, concretely? Would I assign the `myloader.content` a name and check for that name in the loaded "show"?

Comment: name is assigned automatically

Comment: Oh, so I just tried and I did not know this. Flash really assignes the name "root1" to the current running movie. Good to know, and certainly as much of a valid option. +1